# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ' ' with sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error, ssms

I am dynamically building a SQL statement based on operations from a couple of different tables. The salient part of the SQL is below.

```sql
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
...
SELECT @sql = 'TRIM(CAST(' + STRING_AGG(EXPORT_COL, ' AS VARCHAR)) + '','' + TRIM(CAST(') FROM #TEMP_TABLE
SET @sql = 'SELECT''(''+'+@sql+' AS VARCHAR))+'')'''+'FROM '+'[mydatabase].[dbo].['+@TABLENAME+']'
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'''','''''')
```

When I call the code using `sp_executesql`

```sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

I get this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near ''

If I query `@sql` or print the value to the messages window in SSMS I get:

```sql
SELECT''(''+TRIM(CAST(COL1 AS VARCHAR)) + '','' + TRIM(CAST(COL2 AS VARCHAR))+'')''FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[DATA_TABLE]
```

which is the output I would expect.

Copying the text and calling `sp_executesql` using a quoted version of the output string, the query succeeds with no error.

```sql
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT''(''+TRIM(CAST(COL1 AS VARCHAR)) + '','' + TRIM(CAST(COL2 AS VARCHAR))+'')''FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[DATA_TABLE]'
```

I have already checked for the presence of non-printable characters as indicated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730441/incorrect-syntax-near)

I have also implemented a function that "should" strip out any non printable characters per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148767/sql-server-remove-all-non-printable-ascii-characters). Yet the problem persists.

SQL Server 2017 Express (v14.0.1000.169) on Windows Server 2019 standard.

Comment: `PRINT` your dynamic SQL and debug that first, then move the solution to the dynamic statement.

Comment: Also: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Also `'['+@TABLENAME+']'` is *not* safe from injection. Use `QUOTENAME` to safely inject object names.

Comment: @Larnu that was one of the first things I did during debugging. Print and copy of the dynamic SQL succeeds.

Comment: Then so too would sending it to `sys.sp_executesql`. Take the time to make us a [mre] here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be really careful about when and what parts need single quotes vs which parts need doubled quotes.

If you are writing the string to assign it to a variable, it needs the doubled quotes. If, however, the string already has the quote inside, it doesn't need to be doubled again.

Here's a simplified example showing the issues/approach

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (TestVal varchar(100));
INSERT INTO #Test (TestVal) VALUES ('abcde');
```

Now, when running the process with doubled quotes (similar to yours), here are the results

```
DECLARE @SQL2 nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT ''''('''' + TestVal + '''')'''' FROM #Test;'
PRINT @SQL2;
/* -- Result
SELECT ''('' + TestVal + '')'' FROM #Test;
*/

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL2;
/* -- Result
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ''.
*/

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT ''('' + TestVal + '')'' FROM #Test;';
/* -- Result
(abcde)
*/
```

Note that in the bottom command, the doubled quotes were needed so that the string would contain single quotes - and therefore works. However, when already in the string, it made the command fail.

Now, if we make the variable just have single quotes, it works

```
DECLARE @SQL3 nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT ''('' + TestVal + '')'' FROM #Test;'
PRINT @SQL3;
/* -- Result
SELECT '(' + TestVal + ')' FROM #Test;
*/

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL3;
/* -- Result
(abcde)
*/
```

Comment: Your example was precisely what was occurring.