# Simple query gives - Incorrect syntax near ''

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have very simple query:

```
update dbo.myTable
    set [field1] = case when [field2] <> '' 
                     then [field1] = SUBSTRING([field2],1,6) 
                     ELSE [field1] 
                   end
```

Which gives:

> Incorrect syntax near ''

I've already explored
[Incorrect syntax near ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730441/incorrect-syntax-near/19763826)
and tried everything there.

Microsoft SQL Server Enterpris, 14.0.3294.2

Comment: ...THEN [field1] = SUBSTRING([field2],1,6) ...  should be   ...THEN SUBSTRING([field2],1,6)    ... notice the lack of [field1] =

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Uff, what a silly mistake...it's taken from procedure with variables so I forgot to change that.

Comment: Happens to the best of us  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the right syntax, no need to assign it again inside the case statement:

```
update dbo.myTable
    set [field1] = case when [field2] <> '' 
                     then SUBSTRING([field2],1,6) 
                     ELSE [field1] 
                   end
```