# SQL seems to reject insert statement because of slash character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is a duplicate of a previous question I asked. I'm autistic; so I was confused by the Closed message at the top of this and the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73506756/tsql-complains-about-character-in-insert-text-value) where the original question was asked. The message mentioned the word Closed twice impressing upon me that nothing was to be gained from editing the question. I understand now that that was my mistake.

I'm autistic; so reading and writing are challenging for me; so I hardly write outside of stack overflow; so I only ask questions here, after I have thoroughly researched the issue, which I'm concerned with. I can't remember which pages I visited now in regard to this issue; but I will list every page I visit before asking any future question.

I am editing the question per the instructions on the site knowing full well that the actual question is **now fully resolved.**

The INSERT code further below produced the following error within SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2000):

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near '/'

I was asked to inform you what I need to do and what is my desired result? I need to add a record to the tv_show table with the four values below and my desired result is that it runs without error. I'm autistic; so I look at language literally; so I don't know how else to answer the request.

The instructions ask me to add code fences including which language my code pertains to. I'm attempting to do this below.

I'm autistic; so I can only interpret instructions literally.

**Query**

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tv_show] ([show_key], [title], [link], [country]) 
    VALUES ('tt3069720', 'The Amazing Race Canada', 'https://play.google.com/store/tv/show/The_Amazing_Race_Canada?id=htcXfU1OgIk&gl=US&cdid=tvseason-s6Ujv451SErs26EfxRBr5A', 'Canada')
```

The code below creates the table for the insert statement above. This create statement runs without error.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tv_show]
    (
        [show_key] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
        [title] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [link] [varchar](300) NULL,
        [last_source_id] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [last_source_year] [int] NULL,
        [country] [varchar](50) NULL,

        CONSTRAINT [PK_SHOW_KEY] 
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([show_key] ASC)
                        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: SQL Server 15.0.2000 is the original "RTM" release of SQL Server 2019. There have been 17 cumulative updates since then, some fixing major bugs and performance issues. Ref: [KB4518398 - SQL Server 2019 build versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4518398-sql-server-2019-build-versions-782ed548-1cd8-b5c3-a566-8b4f9e20293a)

Comment: Please don't [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73506756/tsql-complains-about-character-in-insert-text-value) questions; there is an edit feature you can use to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73506756/edit) your *original* content to improve it, and get it reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax seems correct. See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f5fee862873a631c6fc0280ae2e8d22e)

One common cause of that error is when you copy the code from a text editor, a web page, etc. and try to run it in SQL server, it sometimes picks up unwanted characters that will cause the query to fail. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730441/incorrect-syntax-near).

> Such unexpected problems can appear when you copy the code from a web
> page or email and the text contains unprintable characters like
> individual CR or LF and non-breaking spaces.

Comment: I will apply the latest cumulative update 17 to my copy of SQL Server 2019. I cut the URL from the Insert code to notepad and back again and it ran correctly. Thanks, all.